# How to set ImageView with URI correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using local database ROOM to store some uri from phone but I can't reload it in the second times.

The exception is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.andiogame, PID: 2878
java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.andiogame has no access to content://media/external/images/media/24
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2385)
```

The code is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(simpleMessage.getUri());
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(simpleMessage.getUri());
imageView.setImageURI(null); 
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: The app shut down immediately with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare permission to read external storage.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also, if you're targeting Android 23+ (which you probably are), you need to ask for permissions at runtime.